# How to modify a video file name on upload, in codeigniter and no_cms?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So what I want to do is change the names of videos just after they are uploaded. I will also need to update the database entry.

The problem I have is I can't find the location to make the modification.

Comment: What does the `$this->load->library('upload', array());` statement look like?

Comment: where would I find this? Sorry complete newbie to CI

Comment: CI is an MVC framework - model, view, controller...you would deal with your uploads in the controller.  You should review some basics before delving in further.

Comment: I'm aware that it is an MVC, and I do know a little about it. The problem I have is that I don't understand how no_cms is dealing with the upload, as this doesn't appear to have any controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I was a able to find the location by reviewing the html locating unique tags. Then running a grep search on all folders for the tags. I then continued down the trail in the same manor until I located the upload php.